# Install mariadb 10.3 on ubuntu 18.04 gpg add key error gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, ubuntu-18.04

When I wanted to install mariadb 10.3 on ubuntu 18.04, first I executed this comment`sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.4x5jDMaALH/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8`

and I got the following error:

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, This thing helped me to add the signature. Just edit your resolve.conf file and added google DNS

just went and added this line to

> /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 # Google dns
```